# ssh git commands authenticating with authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab, bitnami

I have an amazon ec2 cloud server running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-52-virtual x86_64). I have gitlab installed using bitnami image. SSH cloning of repos does not work.

I can not log in as git over ssh with ssh key

```
    ➜  front-end git:(develop) ssh -vT git@cloud.redrockrim.org
    OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to cloud.redrockrim.org [54.229.74.10] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: RSA 54:52:a4:7c:bf:45:bc:89:b5:7f:ae:59:2d:d6:e2:11
    debug1: Host 'cloud.redrockrim.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    git@cloud.redrockrim.org's password:
```

I can log in using ssh as a different user I created.

```
    ➜  front-end git:(develop) ssh -vT redrockrim@cloud.redrockrim.org
    OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to cloud.redrockrim.org [54.229.74.10] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: RSA 54:52:a4:7c:bf:45:bc:89:b5:7f:ae:59:2d:d6:e2:11
    debug1: Host 'cloud.redrockrim.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
    Authenticated to cloud.redrockrim.org ([54.229.74.10]:22).
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: Sending environment.
    debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IE.UTF-8
    debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_IE.UTF-8
    Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-52-virtual x86_64)
           ___ _ _   _  _            _  
          | _ |_) |_| \| |__ _ _ __ (_) 
          | _ \ |  _| .` / _` | '  \| | 
          |___/_|\__|_|\_\__,_|_|_|_|_| 

      *** Welcome to the BitNami GitLab 6.0.0-0 ***
      *** BitNami Wiki:   http://wiki.bitnami.com/ ***
      *** BitNami Forums: http://community.bitnami.com/ ***
```

What can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: On your local machine, run `ssh-keygen -y -f /Users/redrockrim/.ssh/id_rsa` to print out your public key portion. Assuming you have sudo / root access check the contents of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the git@cloud.redrockrim.org user. If you have checked this file and confirm that your public key appears exactly as reported by `ssh-keygen`, could you post a comment confirming this and we'll explore other options.

Comment: I checked the authorized_keys file for the git user, and found the key was defined with a command prefix `command="/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-3",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3...MORE_RSA_KEY_DATA...5sxG8Q== billy@redrockrim.org`. I then added my key by hand, and tried removing all other keys, so can confirm the keys match my local machine keys.

Answer (score 1):

SSH facilities can be suppressed by adding options to the beginning of a key in `authorization_keys`.  What's happening here is the server is preventing your `git` user from having complete/open access to the server with that specific key, but rather only allows a very targeted connection... which is what you'd normally want.

If you want to connect as that user you'd remove the preamble before `ssh-rsa`, although it's all there for good reason.  You can still connect as another user and `su git` once you're on the server... if it's important to be that user for some reason.

**The options mean:**

`command="/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-3"`

Means that this command is executed whenever the connection is made.  *No* command can be supplied by the user.

`no-port-forwarding`

Prevents TCP forwarding

`no-X11-forwarding`

Prevents X11 forwarding

`no-agent-forwarding`

Prevents agent forwarding

`no-pty`

Prevents TTY allocation - what you likely mostly use in ssh to execute commands on the remote server.

Which can all be found on the [ssh(8) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd)

Comment: This is very useful breakdown of the commands. It does not solve my problem. I do need the git user to have key based authentication, to allow `git clone git@server.com/user/repo.git`. For the sake of troubleshooting, I tried replacing all the lines in authorized_keys with only the part from `ssh-rsa ... etc...` and it still does not work.

Comment: I just checked, and it is `-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git 2135 Nov 14 10:27 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` that I am modifying, and there is no `authorized_keys2`.

Comment: What does `grep "git" /etc/passwd` show on the server?  Update `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` line `LogLevel` to `DEBUG1` (or heigher) `service restart sshd` and see what `/var/log/auth.log` shows on the server for the connection attempt {don't forget to switch it back to `INFO` later}